# What's the significance of `string is list` in Tcl

Tags: string, list, tcl

As I understand in Tcl everything is list. so whats the significance of the 
`string is list $var` check?

So far only value of var I could make that check 0 is

`set var \\{` .

For every other value of $var the check results into 1

Comment: Technically, Everything is string in Tcl, not list.

Comment: ya.. just now I edited. it was Typo

Comment: If a command seems to clearly contradict our understanding, we should also (and first?) check our understanding. The ["everything is a list"](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10390) TCL's wiki page starts with "The fact is that not Everything is a list"

Answer (score 2):

From the [man](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M22) page

> list
>
> Any proper list structure, with optional surrounding whitespace.
>   In case of improper list structure, 0 is returned and the varname will
>   contain the index of the “element” where the list parsing fails, or -1
>   if this cannot be determined.

It will help us to find whether the input string is having a valid list structure or not.

Type the following statement in `tclsh`

```
% set x {a {}
```

It will wait for the user to give one more brace to complete the command.

```
% set x {a {}

}
a {}
%
% string is list "{a {}"
0
% string is list "{a {}
}"
1
```

If you have to perform any list related commands, then the input should have a valid list structure.

```
% llength "{a {}"
unmatched open brace in list
%
```

To void this error, you can use `string is list` to ensure it is having a valid structure. (Of course, you can also use `catch` to prevent this error)

Suppose, you may come into a situation where you want to validate the input is having valid list structure, then you can make use of this.

Answer (score 2):

There are all sorts of strings that are not lists. Of course, you could have unbalanced braces, but here's an example with balanced braces:

```
% set str "{this and this}{and that}"
{this and this}{and that}
% string is list $str
0
```

Having non-whitespace characters immediately after the closing brace like that (which can crop up in real-world data all too easily) tends to lead to a non-list being present. The `string is list` command means that instead of guessing whether a specific string is a list or not, you can find out for sure (internally, it runs the string through Tcl's internal list parser and watches for where it goes wrong, if at all).

Most of the time you don't need it, and instead use operations that *definitely* produce lists to clean up your input data instead. (The key ones here are typically `split` and `regexp`, though `scan` and `binary scan` can also help. There are also many parsing utilities in Tcllib.)